# Resetting 'cat' column in GRASS?

Tags: grass-gis, vector, attribute-table

I've got a regular polygon file that looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, this file stems from a `v.overlay` so that the 'cat' values are are a bit messed up. I would like them e.g. to start in the upper left corner and increase from left to right and top to bottom.

How is that possible?
I already tried renaming and updating the columns, but somehow this is never allowed as is touches (of course) the 'cat' column.

Comment: You can use `v.category` to create a new layer with new category values. However, I'm not sure, if it satisfies your needs for that specific pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I am not really sure...the 'cat' column is increasing for me, too, so deleting and adding the 'cat' doesn't change anything. Is it possible to take another columns as cat?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there are some modules, which can take a different category column, than `cat`, but I don't know about any method, which can do this globally.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GRASS module `v.mkgrid`, then "for free" you get two columns "row" and "col" and the cat values are ordered by row, then column.
I suggest you just recreate your grid this way based on the number of rows and columns you need.

Comment: What do you mean by recreate? Maybe this would be the command I'm looking for...

Comment: Just make a new grid layer of however many rows and columns you want with v.mkgrid.

Comment: I tried now `v.mkgrid` and then I need to get the polygon attributes of my old polygons back...so I do again an overlay (of the extacly same polygons) and then the cats are messed up again. I'm turning in circles.
Any Ideas how I could attribute the value of the polygons just to the grid without making the (harmful) overlay?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [v.what.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.what.vect.html) function. The manual says that v.what.vect transfers attributes from the original map's map attribute table into the attribute table of points present in the target map. Although it explicitly refers to *points* in the target map, it seems to work fine when using a polygon vector layer, presumably because it uses the centroids in that case.

For example, if you have a vector layer *A*, with columns P and Q. First create a new grid *B* with the same same extent and number of rows and columns using the [v.mkgrid](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.mkgrid.html) function. Add two new columns P and Q, and use v.what.vect to sample the values from the original vector layer.

```
v.mkgrid map=B grid=10,10
v.db.addcolumn map=B columns="P integer,Q varchar(10)"
v.what.vect map=B column=P query_map=A query_column=P
v.what.vect map=B column=Q query_map=A query_column=Q
```

You can optionally drop the columns created by v.mkgrid

`v.db.dropcolumn map=B@VECEA_species columns=row,col,rown,coln`